# JSF & HTTP Requests

Tags: jsf

let the following code fragment contains a link to `items.xhtml` that lists item names and enables the user to select an item in order to view its details:

```
<?xml ... ?>
<!DOCTYPE ... >
<html ... >
    <h:head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputLink value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/faces/client/items.xhtml">Items</h:outputLink>   
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks the link named `Items`, then the request line states that the resource being requested is `/javaee7-training/faces/client/items.xhtml` and the desired action that should be applied to it is `GET`. That is fine.

The following code shows a fragment of `items.xml`:

```
<?xml ... ?>
<!DOCTYPE ...>
<html ...>
    <h:head>
        <title>items</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.itemId}"
                              layout="pageDirection">
                <c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="itm">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{itm.itemno}" 
                                  itemLabel="#{itm.itemname}" />
                </c:forEach>
            </h:selectOneRadio>

            <h:commandButton value="Details" action="item" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Now when the user clicks the button named `Details`, then the request line states that the resource being requested is `/javaee7-training/faces/client/items.xhtml` and the desired action that should be applied to it is `POST`. I don´t expected this result, because when the user clicks the button named `Details`, then the requested resource is `/javaee7-training/faces/client/item.xhtml` and the desired action is `GET`.

Could anyone explain me this result and why I am wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h:commandButton>` Always fire a post request because it is supposed to inside the `<h:form>`. And forms are always submitted as POST request in JSF arena. If you need to fire GET request use `<h:button>` instead of `<h:commandButton>`.

Usage Example:

```
<h:button value="Click Me!!" outcome="item"> <!--viewId is item insted of items-->
 <f:param name="item1" value="itemVal1" />
 <f:param name="item2" value="itemVal2" />
</h:button>
```

Comment: I agree with @AsSiDe, and you can use a `<h:link outcome="/client/items" value="To Items" />` instead of `outputLink` which doesn't use JSF Navigation.

Comment: Thank you very much for you helpful answer

Comment: @estebanrincon Thank you for your helpful contribution